# Method of Lines for Wave Equation with Periodic Bounday Condition

Tags: method-of-lines

I am trying to solve, using the method of lines in Matlab, the wave equation IVP:

\begin{cases}
      \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} \\
      v(x, 0) = e^{-x^2} & -5\lt x\lt 5 \\
      \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}(x, 0) = 0 \\
      v(-5, t) = v(5, t) 
\end{cases}

I rewrote the wave equation as two coupled equations:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = w\\
\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}
\end{equation}

The second equation is just the heat equation, which I think can be represented by

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}
w_1\\w_2\\\dots\\w_n
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\Delta x^2}\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 1\\ 1 & -2 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 & \dots & 0 \\ \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & -2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
w_1\\w_2\\\dots\\w_n
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where the matrix A is n x n and tridiagonal and the 1's in the top right and bottom left corners provide the periodic boundary condition; or
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\vec{w} = A\vec{w}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\vec{u} = \vec{w}
\end{equation}

I am a little unsure how to plug this into, for example, ode45 in Matlab.

I have done the following:

```
function solns = coupledODEs(t,U)
global A n

len = length(U);
u = U(1:len/2);
w = U(len/2+1:len);


solns(1:len/2) = A*w; %W'
solns(len/2+1:len) = u;  %U'
solns = transpose(solns);
```

```
global A n

xi = -5;
xf = 5;
n = 1000;   % no of grid points Xn
h = (xf-xi)/(n+1.); % grid spacing in x direction


T = 50.; % length of time for solution

r = 1/(h^2);  

A = 2*-r*diag(ones(1, n)) + r*(diag(ones(1, n-1), 1) + diag(ones(1, n-1), -1));
A(n, 1) = r;
A(1, n) = r;

% set up mesh in x-direction:
x = xi:h:xf;
x = x';
x1 = x(1:n);
U0 = exp(-x1.*x1);
W0 = 0*x1;

ICs = [U0; W0];
[t, results] = ode45('coupledODEs',[0,T], ICs);

resultsize = size(results); 

U = results(:, 1:resultsize(2)/2); %capture the first half of the results, which returns U?
```

Visually the wave appears to be passing through the sides like a periodic boundary allows, but I'm not sure how to confirm that it is actually correct. I am not terribly familiar with Matlabs ODE functions. Am I doing this correctly? Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You could use the method of manufactured solutions to check your problem. That is:

1. Add a source term to your original equation.
2. Assume a solution $u_\text{manu}$.
3. Plug the solution in your differential equation and find the corresponding source term.
4. Solve for your source term and see if you obtain $u_\text{manu}$.

Comment: The solution to the wave equation in a periodic domain should have a period that is calculable and therefore the solution comes exactly back to the initial condition.  Also the more canonical way to solve the second order wave equation would be to write this as two advection equations but you do you.

Comment: @KyleMandli can you elaborate on the two advection equations? I've not seen that before.

Comment: The second order wave equation can be factored such that $(\partial_t + \partial_x) (\partial_t - \partial_x) v = 0$.  This gives you two one-way wave equations, better known as advection equations, going in opposite directions.  It is much more common to tackle these first order system of advection equations than the second order, single equation for a number of reasons including difficulty with boundary conditions and ease of implementation of classical methods such as upwinding methods.